# Handle exceptions from multiple methods

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, c#-9.0

I have a method that looks like this

```
private void Foo()
{
   Method1(var1)
   Method2(var1)
   Method3(var2)
   Method4(var3)
   ...
   //lots of methods in a row like this
}
```

How would I implement Exception handling on every method it's calling, without spamming try-catch blocks everywhere? I'm wanting the exception message to be different depending on which method causes the exception.

**Example:**
`Method1()` breaks: show user `"You don't have permissions for this"`
`Method2()` breaks: show user `"File contents are not in the right format"`
`Method3()` breaks: show user `"Error at line 3 in file"`
etc...

Comment: Do you need each method executed, while showing message for each or after all, or break on the first that throws an exception and the following ones not executed?

Answer (score 3):

A very low tech approach maybe to just use an *Action Delegate* with a generic parameter to at least filter by the exception you expect to get

```
public void Check<T>(Action action, string errorMessage ) where T : Exception
{
   try
   {
      action();
   }
   catch (Exception e) when (e is T)
   {
      ShowMessage(errorMessage);
   }
}
```

**Usage**

```
Check<IndexOutOfRangeException>(() => Method1(), "oh darn");
```

Personally though, I think this is a fairly suspect solution, and you should likely rethink your exception handling strategies in full. In short exceptions shouldn't be used for flow control, and catching them should be when you know exactly what do do with them.

Furthermore, the methods implementations should probably use Try style methods if they are available or catch and deal with their own exception when and only when it knows to expect them.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is creating a list of exceptions and adding all exception to that list.

At the end of the system you collect all your exception.

An example of this in your case.

```
private List<Exception> Exceptions = new List<Exception>();
```

Than each method you do following:

```
void Method1(string var1)
{
    try
    {
        //some logic
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Exceptions.Add(e);
    }
}
```

You also make your own error model that has exception property with other property like, time, message etc.

To show the problems at once, you can at the end of the all make a loop some thing like:

```
foreach (var exception in Exceptions)
{
    Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are explicitly throwing new Exceptions based some conditions (handled exceptions), Then you don't need to spam everywhere by putting try-catch statements.

```
        private void Foo()
        {
            try
            {
                Method1(var1);
                Method2(var1);
                Method3(var2);
                Method4(var3);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }           
        }

        private void Method4(object var3)
        {
            throw new Exception("Exception A");
        }

        private void Method3(object var2)
        {
            throw new Exception("Exception B");
        }

        private void Method2(object var1)
        {
            throw new Exception("Exception C");
        }

        private void Method1(object var1)
        {
            throw new Exception("Exception D");
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can throw your identified exception in your each methods like below in its definition line where those methods implemented.

```
    public void Method1() throws NoPermissionException{
    
    }
    
    public void Method2() throws IllegalFormatException {
    
    }
    
    public void Method3() throws ArithmeticException{
    
    }
```

Then in the Foo() method write one try block and relevant catch clauses to catch each and every exception in one place of the code as below.

```
    private void Foo()
{
   try{
      Method1(var1);
      Method2(var1);
      Method3(var2);
      Method4(var3);
   catch(NoPermissionException e){
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
   catch(IllegalFormatException e){
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
   catch(ArithmeticException){
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
   
   ...
   //lots of methods in a row like this
}
```

Comment: I like the approach, but the "throws" syntax looks like Java, not C#. C# doesn't have checked exceptions.

Comment: C# exceptions management is different from (old?) C++: it does not support such method declaration. Also `throws` is not C++...

Comment: you described how to do in java not in c#